# How to live video stream using node API (Read file with chunk logic)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, live-video

I want to make a live video streaming API and send the video buffer chunk data to an HTML.
I am using **rtsp** URL.
The chunk logic does not work. The video only plays for 5 seconds then stops.

**index.js file**

```
const express = require('express');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

const rtspUrl = 'rtsp://zephyr.rtsp.stream/movie?streamKey=64fd08123635440e7adc17ba31de2036';
const chunkDuration = 5; // Duration of each chunk in seconds


app.get('/video', (req, res) => {
  const outputDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'chunks');
  if (!fs.existsSync(outputDirectory)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(outputDirectory);
  }

  const startTime = new Date().getTime();
  const outputFileName = `chunk_${startTime}.mp4`;
  const outputFilePath = path.join(outputDirectory, outputFileName);

  const command = ffmpeg(rtspUrl)
    .inputFormat('rtsp')
    // .inputOptions(['-rtsp_transport tcp'])
    .videoCodec('copy')
    .output(outputFilePath)
    .duration(chunkDuration)
    .on('start', () => {
      console.log(`start ${outputFileName}`);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      console.log(`Chunk ${outputFileName} saved`);
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');
      res.sendFile(outputFilePath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error sending file:', err);
        } else {
          fs.unlinkSync(outputFilePath); // Delete the chunk after it's sent
        }
      });
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('Error: ', error);
    });

  command.run();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`API server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Video Streaming With Node</title>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="videoPlayer" width="50%" controls autoplay>
    <source src="/video" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</body>

</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
.....
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
.....
}
```